# How to insert fastly an attachment as a pdf file in a product page?

Tags: pdf, attachment

Magento 1.9.0.1

I would like to add a pdf file to download in a product page.

In the product description (long or short) there's WYSIWYG editor. In this editor there are command to insert:

- images
- embedded videos
- attributes

I could arrange uploading the file via ftp in a folder and then linking a text to that URL.

Anything to insert fastly an attachment (as a pdf file)?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/enable-pdf-extension-on-wysiwyg-for-magento/) ?

Comment: Nice solution. I'm just wondering how to apply to my store the advice to copy the file **app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml** to the folder **app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/**. This last folder is not present in my Magento installation

Comment: You need to create folder **Mage/Cms/etc** in **app/code/local** and then put **config.xml** so new  file will be at **app/code/local/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml**